# Samsung 970 EVO plus NVME issue with 18.04 LTE

Tags: system-installation, ssd, amd-processor, nvme

I recently put together a machine with Samsung 970 EVO+ NVME. To install Ubuntu on it, I created a usb drive using another Ubuntu machine and following instructions at:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

When I start the process, it doesn’t show me the screen where it says: “The computer currently has no operating system. Erase the disk and install”.

It takes me to the next step to select partitions and there the NVME doesn’t appear.

I even did gparted using the Ubuntu that comes up from the bootable drive and even that isn’t able to detect the NVME.

I am wondering if there are know issues with using this storage device.

Appreciate inputs from the community, thanks!

EDIT: My BIOS is able to detect the NVME hardware there as a 500 GB Samsung 970 EVO plus. I haven't updated the BIOS, but I am guessing BIOS is fine.

EDIT: I am using a X399 motherboard with AMD Threadripper 2920x.

Comment: Have You got the latest bios installed for Your motherboard ?

Comment: In your BIOS, change the disk controller from RAID to SATA/AHCI/similar.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema for your comments. RAID is disabled for my SSD in the BIOS setup. SATA is set to AHCI, however there isn't anything connected to SATA port.

Comment: Thanks @Michal for your comment. I didn't update my BIOS. However the BIOS is able to detect the NVME. So I am guessing that it is not a problem.

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see if the NVME shows up then.

Comment: You can check your BIOS version, either in the BIOS itself, or in Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a `terminal` and type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for a newer version.

Comment: Sure I will try doing both these.

Comment: In addition to UEFI/BIOS update, you should also update SSD firmware.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, I will try the firmware update as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this. I tried different things, but what worked for me was to physically remove the SSD and attach it to a different port. It seems to be that only one port on X399 motherboard supports Samsung 970 EVO+.

Thanks everyone for your help and support. Appreciate it.